# renaming multiple pandas DataFrame values according to a specific value

Tags: python, pandas

This is my dataframe:

```
              A         i         j
0   O-20-003049       NaN       NaN
1             1  0.643284  0.834937
2             2  0.056463  0.394168
3             3  0.773379  0.057465
4             4  0.081585  0.178991
5             5  0.667667  0.004370
6             6  0.672313  0.587615
7   O-20-003104       NaN       NaN
8             1  0.916426  0.739700
9   O-20-003117       NaN       NaN
10            1  0.800776  0.614192
11            2  0.925186  0.980913
12            3  0.503419  0.775606
```

I want to rename the values in Column A so that I get this:

```
            A         x         y
0  O-20-003049.01  0.593312  0.666600
1  O-20-003049.02  0.554129  0.435650
2  O-20-003049.03  0.900707  0.623963
3  O-20-003049.04  0.023075  0.445153
4  O-20-003049.05  0.307908  0.503038
5  O-20-003049.06  0.844624  0.710027
6  O-20-003104.01  0.026914  0.091458
7  O-20-003117.01  0.275906  0.398993
8  O-20-003117.02  0.101117  0.691897
9  O-20-003117.03  0.739183  0.213401
```

This is what I have so far (thanks to the help of Corralien).

```
df1 = pd.read_excel(sample.xlsx", usecols="A")

# Creating a boolean mask
mask = df1["A"].str.startswith("O-")

# Renaming all rows
df1["A"] = df1.loc[mask, "A"].reindex(df1.index).ffill() + "." + df1["A"].str.pad(2, fillchar="0")

# Removing unwanted rows (where mask==True)
df1 = df1[~mask].reset_index(drop=True)
```

When I run this, I get this error message:
Cannot mask with non-boolean array containing NA / NaN values

I then tried adding "== True" to the boolean mask:

```
mask = df1["A"].str.startswith("O-") == True
```

This gets rid of the error message, but the output is still incorrect.

```
                         A
0  O-21-002001.O-21-002001
1                      NaN
2                      NaN
3                      NaN
4                      NaN
5                      NaN
6  O-21-002002.O-21-002002
7                      NaN
8                      NaN
```

Any ideas would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Let's try:

1. replacing numeric indexes with NaN
2. ffilling to bring label forward
3. Filter table to remove label rows
4. Group to add hundredths indicator

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'A': {0: 'O-20-003049', 1: '1', 2: '2', 3: '3',
                         4: '4', 5: '5', 6: '6', 7: 'O-20-003104',
                         8: '1', 9: 'O-20-003117',
                         10: '1', 11: '2', 12: '3'},
                   'i': {0: np.nan, 1: 0.643284, 2: 0.056463,
                         3: 0.773379, 4: 0.081585, 5: 0.667667,
                         6: 0.672313, 7: np.nan, 8: 0.916426,
                         9: np.nan, 10: 0.800776, 11: 0.925186,
                         12: 0.503419},
                   'j': {0: np.nan, 1: 0.834937, 2: 0.394168,
                         3: 0.057465, 4: 0.178991, 5: 0.00437,
                         6: 0.587615, 7: np.nan, 8: 0.7397, 9: np.nan,
                         10: 0.614192, 11: 0.980913, 12: 0.775606}})

# Mask For Non Numeric Values in A
m = df['A'].str.isnumeric()
# Replace Non Numeric Values in A with NaN and FFILL
df['A'] = np.where(m, np.NaN, df['A'])
df['A'] = df['A'].ffill()
# Filter Out Rows Without Data
df = df[m].reset_index(drop=True)
# Add 1/100th marker to A
df['A'] = df['A'] + \
          ((df.groupby((~m).cumsum()).cumcount() + 1) / 100).astype(str)

print(df)
```

`df`:

```
                 A         i         j
0  O-20-0030490.01  0.643284  0.834937
1  O-20-0030490.02  0.056463  0.394168
2  O-20-0030490.03  0.773379  0.057465
3  O-20-0030490.04  0.081585  0.178991
4  O-20-0030490.05  0.667667  0.004370
5  O-20-0030490.06  0.672313  0.587615
6  O-20-0031040.07  0.916426  0.739700
7  O-20-0031170.01  0.800776  0.614192
8  O-20-0031170.02  0.925186  0.980913
9  O-20-0031170.01  0.503419  0.775606
```

Comment: you can use np.where also-> np.where(df.A.str.isnumeric(),np.NAN,df.A) to enhance performance

Comment: You are correct np.where is significantly more performant. updated my answer. Thanks!